# Keep redux store values after redirecting to another page

Tags: react-router, react-redux

When a user clicks a link it will guide the user to a checkout page.

```
selectSlot(slot){
    window.location = `/checkout/${slot.target.value}`
}
```

My approach won't keep the redux store values.
How can I keep those values?

Here are the router definitions

```
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={MainLayout} />
                    <Route exact path="/index.html" component={MainLayout} />
                    <Route path="/checkout" component={CheckoutLayout} />
                    <Route component={NotFound}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
```

Comment: Which version of React Router are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Link` from `react-router-dom` for the purpose and works for me. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md)